# Auto submit a form before submitting a second one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Into my view I have a main form

```
<%= simple_form_for( [ @comparison, @value ], :html => {class: "main-form"} ) do |f| %>
 ...
 <%= f.button :submit, t('.values_form_submit'), class: "btn cta-little cta-little-yellow" %>
<% end %>
```

Into the same view, by clicking to a link, I open a modal which contains a partialized form :

```
<div class="modal fade" id='<%= "editItem_#{item.id}" %>' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 ...
 <%= render partial: 'items/form', locals: { which_item: item, which_url: edit_comparison_item_path(@comparison, item), which_method: :get } %>
 ...
</div>
```

By clicking the partialized form submit button, I'd like to 'auto submit' the main form before to submit the second one.

I try to do this with jquery.

items/form

```
<%= simple_form_for([ @comparison, which_item ], url: which_url, method: which_method, :html => { :class => "col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" }) do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :title %>
 <%= f.input :url, as: :url %>
 <div class="text-center">
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn cta-little cta-little-yellow my-button" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".my-button").on("click", function(){
  $(".main-form").submit();
 });
});
```

But it doesn't works : partialized form is submitted but the main form isn't.
I tried to call the script on opening modal button onclick. In this case the main form is submitted but I don't know how to open the modal after the `redirect_to`.

Forms belong to different controllers.

Did I take the good way ?

Comment: Can you get dynamic id of `"editItem_#{item.id}"` in your javascript script?

Comment: Can you share code inside of items form? I need to know about form id.

Comment: @MuhamadAkbarBinWidayat I updated my post with the form's code. I'm not sure how to pass item's id in my javascript. I tried to add `@item_reference = @item.id` to my controller and add `var data='<%= j @item_reference %>' alert(data)` to my javascript to display data value but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In general, having the modal submit the main form is messy. Just one example: what do you do if there is an error on the main form? Presumably the main form holds the parent table of the items, so if you can't create the model from the main form, there is nothing to hang the items off of. But the user is in the modal, so how is (s)he going to fix items on the main form?

One alternative could be to disable the modal link when the main form is dirty. Another is to disable it when the model is new, but enabled on edit -- that would allow the modal's items to be saved, and the modal wouldn't need to save the main form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/#entry-examples) to your second form. I'm not sure what exactly the name of your items/form so you have to change into its form name id.
Let try to do this.

```
$("#comparison").submit(function( event ) {
  $(".main-form").submit();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Try to remove `event.preventDefault( );`

Comment: I had already tried and in this case, item form is submitted but not main one.
Do you think it could be a redirect_to issue ? Currently, main_form corresponds to values/update action and I `redirect_to edit_comparison_value_path(@comparison, @value)` which is the view which displays main form and edit form